# How to solve a Formatting Error in Pandas Dataframe - Length issue or formatting?

Tags: python, pandas

I am experiencing the error on the last line:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I am not quite sure how to correct this error. I tried using different datetime formulas, but I think I may be mixing things up.

Here is a sample of my df:

```
   Commodity        Blank  Value1  Value 2  Value 3       Date  Month
0  All Wheat          NaN       1        3        4 2020-08-17    NaN
1  All Wheat          NaN       4        4        2 2020-08-17    NaN
2       Corn          NaN       1       12        5 2020-08-17    NaN
3       Corn          NaN       4       24        5 2020-08-17    NaN
4   Soybeans    ENDING MY       2       34       24 2020-08-17    NaN
5   Soybeans    ENDING MY      34        2       34 2020-08-17    NaN
6    Sorghum  STARTING MY       4       45        3 2020-08-17    8.0
7    Sorghum  STARTING MY       4       34        4 2020-08-17    8.0
```

Here is the code:

```
# Create New Column
df['Calendar Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year

# Marketing Year
df.loc[(df['Blank'] != 'ENDING MY') & (df['Commodity'] == 'All Upland Cotton') & (df['Month'] < 8), 'Marketing Year'] = df['Calendar Year'].astype(int) - 1
df.loc[(df['Blank'] != 'ENDING MY') & (df['Commodity'] == 'All Upland Cotton') & (df['Month'] >= 8), 'Marketing Year'] = df['Calendar Year'].astype(int)
df.loc[(df['Blank'] != 'ENDING MY') & (df['Commodity'] == 'All Wheat') & (df['Month'] < 6), 'Marketing Year'] = df['Calendar Year'].astype(int) - 1
df.loc[(df['Blank'] != 'ENDING MY') & (df['Commodity'] == 'All Wheat') & (df['Month'] >= 6), 'Marketing Year'] = df['Calendar Year'].astype(int)
df.loc[(df['Blank'] != 'ENDING MY') & (df['Commodity'] == 'Corn') & (df['Month'] < 9), 'Marketing Year'] = df['Calendar Year'].astype(int) - 1

df.loc[df['Blank'] == 'ENDING MY] = df['Calendar Year'].astype(int) - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Blank'] == 'ENDING MY', 'Marketing Year'] = df['Calendar Year'].astype(int) - 1
```

left out 'marketing year' as identifier. Fixed.